# SetDlgItemInt / GetDlgItemInt APIs and thousands separator confusion

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

For my dialog window I'm filling in numbers into edit boxes using the [SetDlgItemInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645518(v=vs.85).aspx) API. It does a great job by also adding a thousands separator (example for US: `1,024`.)

But when I try to read the integer back from the edit control using [GetDlgItemInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645485(v=vs.85).aspx) API, it fails when the number has a thousands separator.

So what am I doing wrong? These two APIs must be compatible with each other.

PS. *I can obviously format these numbers myself. This question is about these two specific APIs that supposedly do formatting for me.*

Comment: When reading the docs for GetDlgItemInt, it says "The function stops translating when it reaches the end of the text or encounters a **nonnumeric** character." Although it probably parses '-' for negatives...

Comment: What are you doing first to cause `SetDlgItemInt` to format the output? I've never heard nor read of it doing so before. There is no documentation I can locate which also makes this claim that you do. This isn't `c++/cli` (.NET) is it?

Comment: @enhzflep: Oh, you know what. I just realized, what's adding thousands is the up-down control (or `CSpinButtonCtrl` for MFC.) Sorry, nevermind...

Comment: @c00000fd - :) No problem. Perhaps the buddy-control can have its figure read, which would come without a seperator.